# How to hide a color swatch image in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

how can I hide a color swatch image on product details page in magento 1.9 for configurable product that doesn't have a product image.

Answer (score 0):

To hide color swatches goto: System=>Configuration => Configurable Swatches => 'Product Attributes to Show as Swatches in Product Detail' and deselect the color swatch attributes and Save.

Refresh Cache.

http://prntscr.com/fhpapg